# Turn private sub into function

Tags: vb.net

I have the following procedure:

```
    Private Sub btnRptEmployeePayToMarket_MouseDown(ByValsender As Object, ByVal myButton As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRptEmployeePayToMarket.MouseDown

    Static Toggle As Boolean

    If myButton.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then

        If Toggle Then

            descForm.Hide()

        Else

            descForm.lblReportTitle.Text = "Ranges to Market"
            descForm.txtButtonDescription.Text = "Learn how you are currently paying specific departments or jobs compared to market. "
            descForm.Show()

        End If

    End If
    Toggle = Not Toggle

End Sub
```

Since I have about 9 buttons that will performing the same action, but only changing the text in descForm.lblReportTitle and on descForm.txtButtonDescription, how can I accomplish this?

I thought of turning the sub into a function but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Handlers are always Subs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move away from the Toggle flag so that you know when a particular button is toggled or not.

To do this, I keep a Dictionary of Boolean objects, keyed by the name of the button. When the common method is executed, it adds the flag if it does not already exist, uses it to determine the appropriate behavior, and then toggles it.

Here is a rewrite of your code with this logic in place:

```
Private m_cToggleFlags As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)

Private Sub btnRptEmployeePayToMarket_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal myButton As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRptEmployeePayToMarket.MouseDown

    ToggleButton(DirectCast(sender, Control).Name, "Ranges to Market", "Learn how you are currently paying specific departments or jobs compared to market.")
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton(sButtonName As String, sReportTitle As String, sButtonDescription As String)

    If Not m_cToggleFlags.ContainsKey(sButtonName) Then
        m_cToggleFlags.Add(sButtonName, False)
    End If

    If m_cToggleFlags(sButtonName) 
        descForm.Hide()
    Else
        descForm.lblReportTitle.Text = sReportTitle
        descForm.txtButtonDescription.Text = sButtonDescription
        descForm.Show()
    End If

    m_cToggleFlags(sButtonName) = Not m_cToggleFlags(sButtonName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It actually solved 2 other issues I was having with my code. I am pretty new to programming, so I was feeling pretty proud of what my code accomplished, until I saw your code and was humbled. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could add handlers to this sub.

```
Private Sub btnRptEmployeePayToMarket_MouseDown(ByValsender As Object, ByVal myButton As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRptEmployeePayToMarket.MouseDown, btnAnotherone.MouseDown, etc...
```